# Have I installed pandas for python or not (Mac)

Tags: python

Im having problems installing modules to python, I don't really understand anything. pip3 came preinstalled to python 3.7, so I used this to try and install pandas, this is what terminal said. Have I installed pandas or not?

Update: Nope nothing is installed

Comment: did you try `import pandas`? Usually a good indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typing `import pandas` in the interactive python prompt. If you get no errors, it installed successfully.

Comment: RIP I got errors, thank you though, at least I know how to check if modules are installed